# DOTween is not available in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package, dotween

I'm working on the Unity project now and have an error message in VSCode.

> 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'DOMove' and the best extension method overload 'DOTweenModulePhysics2D.DOMove(Rigidbody2D, Vector2, float, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'Rigidbody2D'

```
using DG.Tweening;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.DOMove(new Vector3(1,2,3), 1);
    }
}
```

When I type DOMove in VSCode, the auto-completion for that method does not show up. I tried moving the Demigiant folder from plugins into the main asset directory then moved it back and restarted Unity, but I still get the same error...

Comment: Have you installed "Debugger for Unity" extension in your VSCode?

Comment: joantoh, I have the same problem.
The code compiles and works but VSCode doesn't recognize DOTween, making it hard to write code. Any idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a `using DG.Tweening;` at the top of your file?

If you are using [assembly definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html), you need to add "DOTween-modules" as a dependency. Otherwise the using line will not compile.

Comment: How can I do that? When I install DOTween, it does not come with any asmdef files.

Comment: Ah, you have to open the Dialog it shows at the start, and then select Create ASMDEF.

Answer (score 1):

did u already add `using DG.Tweening` at the file?
if yes try open 'edit > preferences > external tools' then change the "external script editor" to "visual studio code". "Regenerate project files" will be appear then click it. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I **delete** another plugin's **Assembly script**. Than fixed.

*(Plugin was: MAST)*